# Finding solutions linear system that contain only nonzero coordinates

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra

I use the following code to output a list of k solutions of a linear system,

`solns = FindInstance[A.x == zeros, x, Reals, k]`

here `zeros` is defined as `zeros = ConstantArray[0, n]` where `n` is the dimension of my problem.

Now what I would like to find is a solution `x` of `Ax = 0` such that all the entries of `x` are non-zero. My strategy would be too choose a large value for `k`, and filter the list `solns` for solutions that have no zero entries. Is there a more direct / neater way of doing this?

Comment: Nontrivial solutions only exist if `Det[A]==0`!

Comment: You can explore the `NullSpace` command.

Answer (score 1):

You will unlikely find any zeros in the difference between the least square solution for certain values and a random nonzero vector that made the values arise to begin with:

```
# - LeastSquares[A, A.#] &[ConstantArray[1, Dimensions[A][[2]]]]
```

Assuming a solution with your constraints exists that is.